# Problems with a 1 1/4 inch rod holding 4 curtain panels

Tags: windows

I have curtain 4 panels that cover a large French sliding door. We had to use expansion brackets to extend far enough out to cover shades.

The problem is that the anchors he used are not holding well in drywall and the brackets are not strong enough to hold the weight of panels, especially with opening and closing daily.

The rod had to be hung about a foot over molding is are not in studs.

Comment: Is there a question in there that I'm missing?

Comment: I took it as an implicit "how do I fix this", but your point is very valid, @JACK

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how to participate here with upvotes for helpful info and check marks for accepted answers.

Comment: ask a question so we can answer it. Even if it seems that the question is obvious

Answer (score 1):

Are you using hollow wall anchors? That's what you need. There are various types to support different weights. With draperies that are constantly being tugged and pulled you might want to use an anchor that expands out on the interior of the drywall. Below are some examples of different types of hollow wall anchors. You can find more on-line or in your local home center.
However, even with these anchors it is a good idea to try to get at least one of the brackets into a stud if you can. There should be studs behind the trim on the sides of your French doors.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No sure who "he" is, but it sounds like "he" didn't use proper wall anchors when mounting the brackets to the wall.

Any time something is mounted to a wall, the screws or nails should go into the framing studs behind the wall surface (drywall/sheetrock in your case). If the location of a mount point cannot be made to line up with a stud, then a drywall anchor or toggle bolt should be used to support the weight.

For something light, a drywall anchor (sometimes called a "molly") should be used:

[image]
<sup>Image from BobVila.com. No endorsement intended or implied</sup>

However, your 4 curtain panels sound like they're pretty heavy. In that case, I'd recommend a toggle bolt like this:<sup>*</sup>

[image]
<sup>Image from Lowes.com. No endorsement intended or implied</sup>

The one caveat to using this type of anchor for your application is that you have to pass the screw through the hole in the mounting bracket. For each toggle, you'll need to remove the screw from the "butterfly wings", put the screw through the mounting bracket, then reinsert the screw into the "butterfly wings". Once you've done that, you can push the wings through the predrilled hole in the drywall. You then tighten the screw which expands the wings on the other side of the drywall and clamps the wings, drywall and mounting bracket into a nice, tight, sturdy sandwich which will hold significantly more weight than a simple screw into the drywall.

---

<sup>*</sup>Thanks to AlaskaMan for pointing out that I'd posted 2 pics of essentially the same thing while claiming they were different.

Comment: Personally i do not like those anchors for any significant weight at all. If i do use them i pre-drill an appropriate size hole first, otherwise it chews up and loosens the drywall to much and weakens the holding power.  I prefer **Toggle style anchors**. https://www.lowes.com/pl/Toggler--Drywall-anchors-Anchors-Fasteners-Hardware/4294690615?refinement=4294815421

Comment: Heh... I said "toggle bolt like this" then proceeded to _not_ show a toggle bolt. My bad. I agree with your recommendation, @AlaskaMan

Comment: @AlaskaMan better now? ;)